# How to match string containing another string (between two tags) using regex

Tags: php, regex

So this is my data:

```
<code>

add

add(print);

</code>
add();
"add"
'add'
<code>

add

add("add");

</code>

</script>
```

I would like to match every instance of 'add' that is between the `<code>` tags and not inside any double or single quotes, but right now what i got:

```
<code>.*?(add).*?<\/code>
```

is not working.

Can someone please help me out? (I am using regex101.com to do the work)

Comment: `DOMDocument` is a proper tool for such cases

Comment: What programming language should this be in? Add a tag.

Comment: You need a content-aware parser in this kind of cases, which regex isn't. For example, with regex you can't tell that `A` isn't inside a tag here : `<a></a>A<a></a>`, because all regex can tell is that it is both preceded by a tag opening and followed by a tag closing.

Comment: `/<code>[^>]*(add[(][^)]+[)])[^>]*<\/code>/` this might help you

Comment: Use the comments, don't update the question with comments. Use a parser and pull the `code` element, you then can look for all `add`s.